# How to remove all child nodes, but leave the actual data?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Is there a way in jQuery to remove all child nodes, but leave the text in the node?

Such as:

```
<div>
    Hello
    <span>World</span>
</div>
```

The result would be:

```
<div>
    Hello
</div>
```

Comment: Your result is the same as your starting point. Perhaps you meant to remove the `<span>` element, but leave its text?

Comment: those are both the same thing!

Comment: please edit you're answer as the result looks just like nothing was removed. and allso it can be done rather easy, you just need to loop (google: jquery each) thru each children, get the content of the inner html ( google: jquery html()) save it all in one variable then replace the html of the parent node with what you got from each cildren ( google: jquery html()).

Comment: Here is what I wanted. Sorry about that

Comment: i changed my answer to reflect ur updated question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this out:

```
$('div').children().remove()
```

Comment: I did not voted down but it looks like you are complicating something that is quite simple.

Comment: FYI, if this is what he wants, `$('div').children().remove()` works.

Comment: The OP appears to have changed the question! This answer is now correct.

Answer (score 7):

Assuming you actually want:

```
<div>Hello World</div>
```

as a result:

```
var node = $('#yourDiv');
node.text(node.text());
```

Comment: changed this from `node.html(node.text())` since that can cause HTML in text (e.g. a code sample on this page) to be converted to new DOM nodes.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know about that note.text() thing. But it wasn't exactly what I was looking for. +1

Answer (score 0):

Here is an easy plugin to do this for you recursively (if you have multiple depths of children):

```
$.fn.extend({ 
    stripChildren : function() {
       $(this).children().each(function() { 
          if ($(this).children().size() > 0)
            $(this).stripChildren();
          else
            $(this).replaceWith($(this).html());
            $(this).parent().stripChildren();
       }); 
    }
});
```

To use this is simple:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('div').stripChildren();
});
```

Comment: um, that's a really really complex way to say node.html(node.text()); as per my answer.