# Remove all child nodes but leave the text content of the node in javascript (no framework)

Tags: javascript, dom, nodes, removechild

I'm trying to remove all child elements from a node but leave the actual text content of the node. I.e. go from this:

```
<h3>
   MY TEXT
   <a href='...'>Link</a>
   <a href='...'>Link</a>
   <select>
      <option>Value</option>
      <option>Value</option>
   </select>
</h3>
```

to this:

```
<h3>
   MY TEXT
</h3>
```

I know that there are a [million easy ways to do this in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5382763/how-to-remove-all-child-nodes-but-leave-the-actual-data), but it's not an option for this project... I've got to use **plain old javascript**.

This:

```
var obj = document.getElementById("myID");
if ( obj.hasChildNodes() ){
    while ( obj.childNodes){
        obj.removeChild( obj.firstChild );       
    }
}
```

obviously results in just `<h3></h3>`, and when I tried:

```
var h3 = content_block.getElementsByTagName('h3')[0];
var h3_children = h3.getElementsByTagName('*');
for(var i=0;i<h3_children.length;i++){
   h3_children[i].parentNode.removeChild(h3_children[i]);
}
```

It gets hung up part way through. I figured it was having trouble removing the options, but altering the `for` loop to skip removal unless `h3_children[i].parentNode==h3` (i.e. only remove first-level child-elements) stops after removing the first `<a>` element.

I'm sure I'm missing something super obvious here, but perhaps it's time to turn to the crowd. **How can I remove all child elements but leave the first-level `textNodes` alone? And why doesn't the above approach work?**

### EDITS

There are a couple of working solutions posted, which is great, but I'm still a little mystified as to why looping through and removing `h3.getElementsByTagName('*')` doesn't work. [A similar approach](http://jsfiddle.net/BtAPq/)(adapted from [Blender](https://stackoverflow.com/users/464744/blender)) likewise does not complete the process of removing child nodes. Any thoughts as to why this would be?

Comment: Oddly, this removes all but one `<a>` element: http://jsfiddle.net/rSbmR/

Comment: @Blender - Yeah, I was getting similar results with the `getElementsByTagName loop` (removal of most but not all of the elements). Any thoughts as to why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
var h3=content_block.getElementsByTagName("h3")[0];
for(var i=0;i<h3.childNodes.length;i++)
{
  if(h3.childNodes[i].nodeType==3)//TEXT_NODE
  {
    continue;
  }
  else
  {
    h3.removeChild(h3.childNodes[i]);
    i--;
  }
}
```

[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/BnSvw/)

**Edit**:

Combined the `i--` to make it look shorter:

```js
var h3=content_block.getElementsByTagName("h3")[0];
for(var i=0;i<h3.childNodes.length;i++)
{
  if(h3.childNodes[i].nodeType==3)//TEXT_NODE
    continue;
  else
    h3.removeChild(h3.childNodes[i--]);
}
```

**Edit** #2:

Pointed out by @SomeGuy, make it even shorter:

```js
var h3=content_block.getElementsByTagName("h3")[0];
for(var i=0;i<h3.childNodes.length;i++)
{
  if(h3.childNodes[i].nodeType!=3)//not TEXT_NODE
    h3.removeChild(h3.childNodes[i--]);
}
```

The brackets can be removed too, but that would be "less readable" and "confusing", so I keep it there.

Comment: Good man! I figured I probably needed to run a check for `[x].nodeType==3` but I didn't think to use `h3.childNodes.length`... I kept trying to figure out how to use `while ( obj.childNodes)` without creating an infinite loop. **Any idea why the `getElementsByTagName() loop` didn't work?**

Comment: @BenD Notice the `i--` in my answer? Whenever you removed a child, the parent node's `childNodes.length` is shorten by 1, so you have to "step back" your iterator too. Otherwise you would end up with calling `h3_children[3]` while it only has 2 children left.

Comment: It could be just `if (lala.nodeType != 3) remove`, even shorter without meaningless continue branch.

Comment: @SomeGuy Thanks! I love your solution, by the way.

Answer (score 1):

You can check properties `.nodeType` or `.nodeName` for each node.

Text nodes have these properties set to:

```
.nodeType == 3
.nodeName == '#text'`
```

Answer (score 1):

For instance:

```
var e = obj.firstChild
while (e) {
   if (e.nodeType == 3) {
      e = e.nextSibling
   } else {
      var n = e.nextSibling
      obj.removeChild(e)
      e = n
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this. I am assuming you will keep ant text here.

```
var h3 = document.getElementsByTagName('h3')[0];

if (h3.hasChildNodes()) {
    for (var i = h3.childNodes.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (h3.childNodes[i].nodeName != "#text")
            h3.removeChild(h3.childNodes[i]);
    }
}
```

Hope it will work.

Comment: very similar to Passerby's answer, but it does work, and it's a slightly shorter syntax

Answer (score 0):

Well, The thing I used (inspired from the answers here) is somewhat like:

```
   var h3 = document.getElementsByTagName("h3")[0];
    Array.protoype.filter.call(h3.childNodes, function(child){
        if (child.nodeType != 3) {
            h3.removeChild(child);
        }
    });
```